# Openni skeleton tracker does not post transforms

Tags: kinect, openni, tracking, openi-tracker, skeleton

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am trying to use the openni skeleton tracker with kinect. We are starting openni with default parameters and openni_tracker:

```
$ roslaunch openni openni.launch
$ rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker
```

And it basically seems to detect the human and the PSI-pose, but i cannot get any visualization in RVIZ. As far as i understand the code, the skeleton-transforms should be posted via tf? Also i cannot find the "Prime Sense User Tracker Viewer" anywhere...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12698/openni-skeleton-tracker-does-not-post-transforms/) by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what are your RVIZ configs ? you have to add a tf frame to rviz!
Enter "rostopic list" command in console and make sure that tf topic is exist and also do a "rostopic echo /tf" to make sure that transforms are posted to tf topic!
I think something similar to "Sense User Tracker Viewer" is exist in pi_tracker package!

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-02-06**:
Sorry for late, the pi_tracker worked for us!

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-01-19**:
Thanks for your answer. I already added tf to the RVIZ config and checked if the transforms are beiing sent with 'rostopic echo /tf', but only the camera frames appear... I will test with the pi_tracker package now...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/tf topics will be published when it has started tracking the User. Before 'tracking' you cannot visualize anything in the rviz. Just make sure you have added the TF and select /openni_depth_frame as Fixed/Reference frame .

Second option is to use the ros openni_tracker on offline data. Record a '.oni' file with Openni Sample NiViewer and then run the ros openni_tracker on this recorded data.
For implementation details please checkout my post.

[http://tayyabnaseer.blogspot.de/2012/04/running-ros-openni-tracker-with.html]

---

Originally posted by [tayyab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2123/tayyab/) with karma: 59 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1